# How many ways to distribute 19 identical objects to 4 distinct people so everyone gets at most 5?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways to distribute 19 identical objects to 4 distinct people so everyone gets at most 5?

I know to distribute r identical objects to n groups it's n^r...
So I have 4^19

But I don't know how to deal with the fact that everyone gets at most 5.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that all $19$ objects are distributed, let each one get $n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4$, we have $\sum n_i = 19$, with each $n_i \le 5$

Consider variables $y_i = 5 - n_i$, then the constraints become $\sum y_i = 1$.

So given that $y_i$ can only take values $0$ and $1$, we will have only $\color{blue}{4}$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

If everyone gets at most $5$, the distribution must be $\{5,5,5,4\}$ in some order. How many different orders are possible?

Comment: 4! right? So (4^19) * 4! ?

Comment: @DavidDonaldson No.  There are only 4 ways.

Comment: sorry I edited it, what if it was 6 people by the way? would it be (4^19) * 6!

Comment: @DavidDonaldson in that case see the approach I have taken in my answer. You can work along those lines

Comment: @Shailesh David Donaldson is correct. There should not be any $(4^19)$ anywhere. If there were $6$ people, it would be more complicated, and David's approach will work in general. You can solve it as a Stars and Bars problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) after converting from the $n_i\leq 5$ to the $y_i=5-n_i \geq  0$.